# How to combine two vectors into a single data structure, and then loop over it?

Tags: r

I'm trying to avoid duplicating code for looping over two sets of files ('yes' and 'no' model training files), so I'm combining two vectors of filenames into one data.frame along with an additional bit of metadata to keep track of whether a file is a 'yes' file or a 'no' file. The resulting data structure looks right, but then I can't figure out how to loop over the data.frame.

***Perhaps the best solution is to combine the two vectors into a different type of data structure (i.e. not a data.frame)?***

```
> yesFiles = c("yFile1", "yFile2", "yFile3", "yFile4")
> noFiles = c("nFile1", "nFile2", "nFile3", "nFile4")
> allFiles = data.frame(result=c(rep("yes", times=length(yesFiles)), rep("no", times=length(noFiles))), name=c(yesFiles, noFiles))
> allFiles
  result   name
1    yes yFile1
2    yes yFile2
3    yes yFile3
4    yes yFile4
5     no nFile1
6     no nFile2
7     no nFile3
8     no nFile4
> 
> for (file in allFiles) { cat(sep="", file$result, ": ", file$name, "\n") }
Error in file$result : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>
> for (file in allFiles) { cat(sep="", file['result'], ": ", file['name'], "\n") }
NA: NA
NA: NA
>
```

The loop seems to be looping over the columns, not the rows. How can I make it loop over the rows? Or is there a better way to combine the data to permit looping over them all in a single loop?

So then I tried looping over the same structure differently and that still didn't work...

```
> yesFiles = c("yFile1", "yFile2", "yFile3", "yFile4")
> noFiles = c("nFile1", "nFile2", "nFile3", "nFile4")
> allFiles = data.frame(result=c(rep("yes", times=length(yesFiles)), rep("no", times=length(noFiles))), name=c(yesFiles, noFiles))
> allFiles
  result   name
1    yes yFile1
2    yes yFile2
3    yes yFile3
4    yes yFile4
5     no nFile1
6     no nFile2
7     no nFile3
8     no nFile4
> 
> allFiles[1,1]
[1] yes
Levels: no yes
> allFiles[1,2]
[1] yFile1
Levels: nFile1 nFile2 nFile3 nFile4 yFile1 yFile2 yFile3 yFile4
> # ...ah, great! These seem to be giving me what I need.
> 
> for (i in 1:nrow(allFiles)) {
+    result = allFiles[i,1]
+    file = allFiles[i,2]
+    cat(sep="", "File '", file, "' is a '", result, "' file.\n")
+ }
File '5' is a '2' file.
File '6' is a '2' file.
File '7' is a '2' file.
File '8' is a '2' file.
File '1' is a '1' file.
File '2' is a '1' file.
File '3' is a '1' file.
File '4' is a '1' file.
> # ...wha? What's up with the numbers? I thought [1,1], etc, gave strings!
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

---

---

---

---

***The following is additional information*** about what I need to actually do inside the loop, ***requested by 'Colonel Beauvel'*** in a comment below his answer.....

First of all, a utility function I need for converting text timestamps on each row of the .csv files:

```
#-----------------------------------------------
# Read a text timestamp of the form "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.xxx",
# where xxx=milliseconds. Returns a numeric value of the seconds
# since Jan 1 1970, with millisecond precision (i.e. 3 decimal places).
#
readTimestamp = function (tstamp) {
  as.numeric(strptime(tstamp,format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.')) +
  as.numeric(substr(tstamp,20,23))
}
```

Now, the loop I'd like to be running (the code has not been debugged, so I'm sure there are problems with it):

```
colnamesToKeep = union("Seconds", sensorNamesForThisModel)
dataset = list() # Eventually 'dataset' will hold all training data from all files
for (file in allFiles)
{
   cat(sep="", "Reading '", file['result'], "' file \"", file['name'], "\".\n")
   tmp = read.csv(file['name'], na.strings=c(".", "NA", "", "?"), strip.white=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")
   attr(tmp, "names")[1] = "Seconds"   # Rename column 1 to "Seconds" (it's not yet, but it will be)
   tmp = tmp[,-2:-4]      # Delete these columns; they're irrelevant to the KSVM model
   beginTime = readTimestamp(tmp[1,1])
   # Convert column 1 from text timestamps to numeric seconds (msec precision) starting at 0.000
   tmp[,1] = readTimestamp(tmp[,1]) - beginTime
   # Delete all columns for sensors that this model cares nothing about...
   colIndicesToDelete = -which(!(colnames(tmp) %in% colnamesToKeep))
   tmp = tmp[,colIndicesToDelete] # Delete all columns for sensors that this model cares nothing about
   dataset[[length(dataset)+1]] = list(result=file['result'], data=tmp) # Add this to the training dataset
}
```

I am open to any & all suggestions, including and especially for "you shouldn't be using `union()` to create your `colnamesToKeep` variable". Thank you very much!

Comment: The files are .csv files that I will use for training a `ksvm` model. The .csv files are in a format that our legacy software already produces, and I will be reading them in with `read.csv()`, deleting unnecessary columns, converting one column from a text timestamp to a numeric number of seconds and rebasing them such that the first row starts at "time zero", and then feeding them in as input to train the model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, shown below. But I am still very open to suggestions about doing it a better way.

```
> yesFiles = c("yFile1", "yFile2", "yFile3", "yFile4")
> noFiles = c("nFile1", "nFile2", "nFile3", "nFile4")
> allFiles = data.frame(result=c(rep("yes", times=length(yesFiles)), rep("no", times=length(noFiles))), name=c(yesFiles, noFiles))
> allFiles
  result   name
1    yes yFile1
2    yes yFile2
3    yes yFile3
4    yes yFile4
5     no nFile1
6     no nFile2
7     no nFile3
8     no nFile4
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> for (i in 1:nrow(allFiles)) {
+    result = as.character(allFiles[[i,1]])
+    file = as.character(allFiles[[i,2]])
+    cat(sep="", "File '", file, "' is a '", result, "' file.\n")
+ }
File 'yFile1' is a 'yes' file.
File 'yFile2' is a 'yes' file.
File 'yFile3' is a 'yes' file.
File 'yFile4' is a 'yes' file.
File 'nFile1' is a 'no' file.
File 'nFile2' is a 'no' file.
File 'nFile3' is a 'no' file.
File 'nFile4' is a 'no' file.
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an index i of length(files) and use it to subset the data frame once you're looping over it. You can extract a column i's value by using df$column[i]:

```
yesFiles = c("yFile1", "yFile2", "yFile3", "yFile4")
noFiles = c("nFile1", "nFile2", "nFile3", "nFile4")
files = data.frame(result=c(rep("yes", times=length(yesFiles)), rep("no", times=length(noFiles))), 
                      name=c(yesFiles, noFiles),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
files

for (i in 1:length(files$name)) { 
  cat(sep="", files$result[i], ": ", files$name[i], "\n") 
  # Do other stuff here, the filepath is available via files$result[i]
  }

>yes: yFile1
>yes: yFile2
>yes: yFile3
>yes: yFile4
>no: nFile1
>no: nFile2
>no: nFile3
>no: nFile4
```